# scrollbar height in jscrollpane (jquery)

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I've been messing around for hours now trying to adjust the height of the .jspVerticalBar.  it appears that default is setting the height of the bar to 100% of the panes height.

does anyone know where to set this?   i'm not talking about the draggable portion, but the entire bar.

for example

currently it's like this:

:up
|
|
|
|
|
:down

but i want to make it smaller.

:up
|
|
|
:down

unfortunately i have no code to paste because i don't know what code TO paste :)
but the lib is here, if anyone is familiar
https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [this demo](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/caps.html), it seems you need to add "caps" to your scrollbar.

So using the example from that page, something like,

```
.jspVerticalBar .jspCap
{
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
}
```

In the example, `showArrows:true;` is also added to the initialisation of jSrollPane, it's not mentioned whether this is required or not though. *(See update)*

It doesn't seem to mention how you can add a different sized "cap" to the top than you do the bottom though, which I guess means the scrollbar will always be centred on the content, 
but I only had a quick look so there may be a way to do this. *(See Update)*

---

**Update:**

Thanks to vitch in his comment. Apparently `showArrows:true` is not required, and as well as `.jspCap` you have `.jspCapTop`, `.jspCapBottom`, `.jspCapLeft`, and, `.jspCapRight` to modify the caps individually.

---

Pleas note, I haven't used jScrollPane and this is untested, but hopefully it may be helpful.

Comment: Hi tjm, thanks for the tip.  i had tried the .jspCap style and it had no effect.  i will mess with it some more.  maybe im doing something incorrectly.

Comment: @that_guy. No problem, I should point out that in the example, he also adds `display:block;` to the `.jspCap` and passes `showArrows:true` to the jScrollPane initialisation function. Whether either, or both, of these are required I don't know but you may, if you haven't already, want to try with them. I've updated the question with this information.

Comment: Yep - caps are the way to do it. To add a little more information:

 * `showArrows` shouldn't be required for the caps to function.

 * You can size each of the four possible caps differently - as well as a class of `.jspCap` they also get one of `.jspCapTop`, `.jspCapBottom`, `.jspCapLeft` or `.jspCapRight`